# Mule-How to run soap magento calls manually not using Magento connector

Tags: magento, mule, anypoint-studio

As of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34075054/mule-product-not-exists-error) error where I couldn't find a solution, I am trying to run call manually not using Magento plugin.

**EDIT**

Tried something like this:

```
<flow name="restorderSub_Flow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8080" path="test"  doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <parse-template location="src/main/resources/login.xml" doc:name="Parse Template"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2_soap/?wsdl" method="POST" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>
```

But it's just displaying the magneto endpoint in this case it;s the wsdl file??

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to try is using the Web Service Consumer connector, if you have the WSDL available.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/web-service-consumer

Pass in your arguments via DataWeave (when using EE) or via a Parse Template transformer when not using EE.

Comment: Can i pass more then one argument with this connector? I am getting this 'Warning: Operation Messages With More Than 1 Part Are Not Supported.'

Comment: a part is different that an argument, if you are running EE use DataWeave in front of the Web Service Consumer connector

Comment: I am running EE I tried using DataWeave  in front of the Web Service Consumer, but it displays in the output only one argument (in this case is the session id), What wrong?

Comment: I recommend reading the docs here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/web-service-consumer#configuring-web-service-consumer  you specify an operation in the Web Service Consumer connector, so that operation only accept one argument? check with SOAP UI otherwise.

Comment: Okay, It's my mistake! magneto wsdl uses parts and not argument as I wort above, So any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could use http connector to manually send a request. Here is a sample soap request in logging in to magento soap api.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <urn:login soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <username xsi:type="xsd:string">#[message.outboundProperties['magento.username']]</username>
        <apiKey xsi:type="xsd:string">#[message.outboundProperties['magento.password']]</apiKey>
    </urn:login>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: Can you provide a full example for use in Mule(Anypoint Studio)?

Comment: You could create an http inbound endpoint and use parse template to load the xml above and another http outbound endpoint containing the magento api endpoint